# Request using Curl (Windows 10) in Matlab gives error message

Tags: matlab, curl

I am sending a curl command to a server, but get an error message which I do not understand.

The request I need to send to the server is

```
body=$(cat << EOF
{
  "order": {
    "units": "100",
    "instrument": "EUR_USD",
    "timeInForce": "FOK",
    "type": "MARKET",
    "positionFill": "DEFAULT"
  }
}
EOF
)

curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN>" \
  -d "$body" \
  "https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v3/accounts/<ACCOUNT>/orders"
```

What I do is that I translate this into a curl command like :

curlcmd = 'curl -s \ -X POST \ -H "Content-Type: application/json" \ -H "Authorization: Bearer " \ -d "{"order": {"units": "100", "instrument": "EUR_USD", "timeInForce": "FOK", "type": "MARKET", "positionFill": "DEFAULT" }}" \ "https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com/v3/accounts/AccountID/orders"'

I send the command via resp = system (curlcmd) via Matlab to the server. What I get as an error message is :

errorMessage: 'Invalid JSON, ParseErrorCode: 4, Message: Missing a name for object member.'

Any idea what this means and how I can solve this ? I am using Matlab on Windows 10, so curl is part of Windows 10.

Response should be a placed order and response data of the trade.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON doesn't seem to be properly quoted.

Try this:

```
curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer " -d "{\"order\": {\"units\": \"100\", \"instrument\": \"EUR_USD\", \"timeInForce\": \"FOK\", \"type\": \"MARKET\", \"positionFill\": \"DEFAULT\" }}" "https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com/v3/accounts/AccountID/orders"
```

**Test with Proxy**

With the appropriate escape of the JSON quotes, as shown in the above CURL command line, the JSON looks correct when viewed in an HTTPS proxy:

[image: proxy output]